# Translation of statements to logical notation

Tags: logic, predicate-logic, first-order-logic, quantifiers

I have recently started learning **logic** and I came to know how to translate statement into logical notation using propositional functions and quantifiers.
I came across the following problems which are a little bit heavy for me.

We have to translate them into logical notation.

1. Some horses are gentle and have been well trained.
2. Some horses are gentle only if they have been well trained.
3. Some horses are gentle if they have been well trained.
4. Any horse is gentle that has been well trained.
5. No horse is gentle unless it has been well trained.
6. Any horse is gentle if it has been well trained.
7. Any horse has been well trained if it is gentle.
8. Any horse is gentle if and only if it has been well trained.
9. Gentle horses have been well trained.

I have translated them as follows.

Here $H(x)$ ,$G(x)$, $T(x)$ means  $x$ is a horse, $x$ is gentle and $x$ is well trained respectively.

1. ($\exists$ $x$) ($H(x)$$\cdot$$G(x)$ $\cdot$$T(x)$).
2. ($\exists$ $x$) ($H(x)$ $\cdot$ ($T(x)$ $\rightarrow$ $G(x)$ )).
3. ($\exists$ $x$) ($H(x)$ $\cdot$ ($G(x)$ $\rightarrow$ $T(x)$ )).
4. ($\forall$ $x$) ($ H(x)$ $\cdot$ $T(x)$ $ \rightarrow$  $ G(x)$ ).
5. ($\forall$ $x$) ($ H(x) $ $\cdot$ $G(x) $ $\rightarrow$ $ T(x)$ ).
6. Same as 4.
7. Same as 5.
8. Unable to translate.(help needed)
9. Same as 4.

   Here $\cdot$ means $and$.

   Are my translations right ? If I have done any mistake please let me know.

   It's a long question ! So sorry for that. But I am stuck at these problems.
   Hope to get help.
   Thanks.

Comment: For 8, perhaps $\forall x, H(x) \rightarrow [G(x) \leftrightarrow T(x)]$. This means "For every x, being a horse implies that (being gentle occurs if and only if being trained does)"

Comment: @user326210 yes, that's right for 8

Answer (score 1):

You should swap the answers to 2 and 3:

'Gentle if well-trained' means 'if well-trained then gentle', while 'gentle only if well-trained' means 'if gentle then well-trained'

4 through 9 all need universals ($\forall $)

9 is like 5, not 4

8 is $\forall x (H(x) \rightarrow (G(x) \leftrightarrow T(x)))$

Comment: Oh ! There I have done it mistakenly, I have edited now.Are my answers right now ?

Comment: I think there is no #10. Also I read #9 as an existential "[Some] gentle horses have been well-trained". Is this right?

Comment: 9 should be same as 5, not 4

Comment: @user326210 oh, right, only 9.  But 9 is a universal. It's like saying "politicians are corrupt": that's not saying some politicians, but all politicians.

Comment: @Bram28 I think leaving off an article can sometimes be existential and sometimes universal: "People are waiting in the library" [existential], versus "Fish live in water" [universal], "Stones have been set aside for the roof" [existential], "Stones are useful for building" [universal]

Comment: @user326210 True, but 9 is like the latter. It's like "smart people take my advice" :)

Comment: I can see that.  "Gentle horses have been well-trained: horses start off being wild, but once you see them become docile, you know that they are well-trained." (universal). On the other hand, "Gentle horses have been well-trained: we have attempted to domesticate these wild horses, and have succeeded in training a few of the gentler ones." (existential). I don't see anything about the syntax makes it one way or the other; I think it depends on your background assumptions about when someone would say something like this.

Comment: @user326210 OK, I can see that too. I suppose we can agree that English is ambiguous and care must be taken to express yourself clearly! :)

Comment: I got it @Bram28.. are othets right (viz. 1,4,5,6,7) ?

Comment: @Bram28 Yes! :)

Comment: @HirenGarai yes, the others are all ok! 5 is pretty nasty ... was that a lucky guess?  Anyway, as a general tip: whenever you see 'unless', substitute 'if not'. So,  we can paraphrase 5 as: 'all horses are not gentle if not well trained', which would translate as $\forall x (H(x) \rightarrow (\neg T(x) \rightarrow \neg G(x)))$, and by contraposition of the latter conditional, you do indeed get what you have. Good job!

Comment: Yes, that was a lucky guess, @Bram28. And thanks for the tip,I hopr it will help me in near future...